# Troubles using Stanford Arabic Segmenter

Tags: stanford-nlp, arabic

I'm having troubles running the Stanford Arabic segmenter in Windows 10, as whenever I try to process the command as mentioned in the readme file, it fails to load the segmenter data/arabic-segmenter-atb+bn+arztrain.ser.gz

I'm not very familiar with Java so I don't even know whether I understood the classpath matter correctly. Guess, I didn't. Also, I find the readme instructions slightly confusing.

```
Loaded ArabicTokenizer with options: null
loadClassifier=data/arabic-segmenter-atb+bn+arztrain.ser.gz
textFile=C:\Users\vmumm\OneDrive\Ulmo\Nizar\OLD\complete_NQ_new_April2019.txt
featureFactory=edu.stanford.nlp.international.arabic.process.StartAndEndArabicSegmenterFeatureFactory
Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Failed to load segmenter data/arabic-segmenter-atb+bn+arztrain.ser.gz
        at edu.stanford.nlp.international.arabic.process.ArabicSegmenter.loadSegmenter(ArabicSegmenter.java:466)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.international.arabic.process.ArabicSegmenter.getSegmenter(ArabicSegmenter.java:629)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.international.arabic.process.ArabicSegmenter.main(ArabicSegmenter.java:532)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "data/arabic-segmenter-atb+bn+arztrain.ser.gz" as class path, filename or URL
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:480)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1503)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.getClassifier(CRFClassifier.java:2939)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.international.arabic.process.ArabicSegmenter.loadSegmenter(ArabicSegmenter.java:464)
```

I guess, I just need a simple guide how to run the segmenter - assuming that I don't usually work with Java.

Comment: Are you running this from the command line on Windows 10?  If so, what command did you run?  It's possible this is a CLASSPATH issue since it's not finding the segmenter model.

Comment: I posted an example for DOS prompt below that should hopefully work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend downloading the full Stanford CoreNLP package.

1. Download Stanford CoreNLP from here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html
2. This should end up in a directory like:

   ```
   C:\Users\myusername\stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05
   ```
3. Download the Arabic models jar from that same link, and move it to the Stanford CoreNLP directory `C:\Users\myusername\stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05`
4. Set CLASSPATH to include that directory which has all *.jar files you need.

   ```
   set CLASSPATH=C:\Users\myusername\stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05\*;
   ```
5. Run a pipeline on example text (make sure to be in the directory with the example file when you run this command)

   ```
   java -Xmx5g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props StanfordCoreNLP-arabic.properties -file example.txt -outputFormat text
   ```

You should get segmented output in `example.txt.out` when this command finishes.

I don't have access to a Windows machine, so if my answer doesn't work please let me know, and I'll fix it.  I'll try to put up some documentation on our site about working with Windows.

Comment: Also I should add in you can scale back the annotation to just segmentation with `-annotators tokenize,ssplit` if you don't want the other annotations